# Robots.txt and Sitemap.xml on OctoberCms

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I'm using OctoberCMS to create and manage my website, everything is working as it should.

However, I'm having trouble creating the Robots.txt file and the Sitemap.xml file from my site.

The octobercms works with the folder named "themes" I can not just put the files in it. I tried putting the files in the themes folder and gave routes error.

Comment: did you see my answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Or the easier way is to just create a robots.txt file in your web root directory
then allow it to be accessed via .htaccess

`RewriteRule ^robots.txt - [L]`

Answer (score 0):

Create ***robots.htm*** file in themes/***YOUR_THEME***/pages folder
and put below content into it

```
url = "/robots.txt"
==

<--- WRITE YOUR CODE HERE --->
```

and it will start working as you requested. you can do same for sitemap.xml file too but you just need to do small change into it.

```
url = "/sitemap.xml"
==

<--- WRITE YOUR CODE HERE --->
```

***Comment below if you need more help.
Thanks***

Comment: That's not practical, it is better to handle these two from Within your routes and return proper response header and format.